# How is spectral norm of a parameter calculated?

Tags: python, pytorch

when I do,

```
import torch, torch.nn as nn
x = nn.Linear(3, 3)
y = torch.nn.utils.spectral_norm(x)
```

then it gives four different weight matrices,

`y.weight_u`

```
tensor([ 0.6534, -0.1644,  0.7390])
```

`y.weight_orig`

```
Parameter containing:
tensor([[ 0.2538,  0.3196,  0.3380],
        [ 0.4946,  0.0519,  0.1022],
        [-0.5549, -0.0401,  0.1654]], requires_grad=True)
```

`y.weight_v`

```
tensor([-0.3650,  0.2870,  0.8857])
```

`y.weight`

```
tensor([[ 0.5556,  0.6997,  0.7399],
        [ 1.0827,  0.1137,  0.2237],
        [-1.2149, -0.0878,  0.3622]], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
```

how are these four matrices calculated?

Answer (score 8):

I just finished reading the paper for this method which can be found [on arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05957.pdf). If you have the appropriate mathematical background I would recommend reading it. See appendix A for the power algorithm which describes what u and v are.

That said I'll try to summarize here.

First, you should know that the spectral norm of a matrix is the maximum singular value. The authors propose finding the spectral norm of weight matrix `W`, then dividing `W` by its spectral norm to make it close to `1` (justification for this decision is in the paper).

While we could just use `torch.svd` to find a precise estimate of the singular values, they instead use a fast (but imprecise) method called "power iteration". Long story short, the `weight_u` and `weight_v` are rough approximations of the left and right singular vectors corresponding to the largest singular value of W. They are useful because the associated singular value, i.e. the spectral norm, of W is equal to `u.transpose(1,0) @ W @ v` if `u` and `v` are the actual left/right singular vectors of `W`.

- `y.weight_orig` contains the original values in the layer.
- `y.weight_u` is the approximation of the first left singular vector of `y.weight_orig`.
- `y.weight_v` is the approximation of the first right singular vector of `y.weight_orig`.
- `y.weight` is the updated weight matrix which is `y.weight_orig` divided by its approximate spectral norm.

We can verify these claims by showing that the actual left and right singular vectors are nearly parallel to `y.weight_u` and `y.weight_v`

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# pytorch default is 1
n_power_iterations = 1

y = nn.Linear(3,3)
y = nn.utils.spectral_norm(y, n_power_iterations=n_power_iterations)

# spectral normalization is performed during forward pre hook for technical reasons, we
# need to send something through the layer to ensure normalization is applied
# NOTE: After this is performed, x.weight is changed in place!
_ = y(torch.randn(1,3))

# test svd vs. spectral_norm u/v estimates
u,s,v = torch.svd(y.weight_orig)
cos_err_u = 1.0 - torch.abs(torch.dot(y.weight_u, u[:, 0])).item()
cos_err_v = 1.0 - torch.abs(torch.dot(y.weight_v, v[:, 0])).item()
print('u-estimate cosine error:', cos_err_u)
print('v-estimate cosine error:', cos_err_v)

# singular values
actual_orig_sn = s[0].item()
approx_orig_sn = (y.weight_u @ y.weight_orig @ y.weight_v).item()
print('Actual original spectral norm:', actual_orig_sn)
print('Approximate original spectral norm:', approx_orig_sn)

# updated weights singular values
u,s_new,v = torch.svd(y.weight.data, compute_uv=False)
actual_sn = s_new[0].item()
print('Actual updated spectral norm:', actual_sn)
print('Desired updated spectral norm: 1.0')
```

which results in

```
u-estimate cosine error: 0.00764310359954834
v-estimate cosine error: 0.034041762351989746
Actual original spectral norm: 0.8086231350898743
Approximate original spectral norm: 0.7871124148368835
Actual updated spectral norm: 1.0273288488388062
Desired updated spectral norm: 1.0
```

Increasing the `n_power_iterations` parameter will increase the accuracy of the estimate at the cost of computation time.

Comment: is the eventual goal of finding norms related to loss vs weight representing a convex curve, and does this norm less than 1, imply something as to making this curve convex, and dividing weights by different kinds of norm are to achieve convexity? and why do we not make the weight matrix symmetric first, by w = w@w.t(), where @ represents matrix multiplication, or even positive definite, if we want to find singular values?

Comment: According to the authors it's actually about ensuring that the linear layer represents a Lipschitz continuous function (basically a bound on the gradients) to constrain the amount of learning a discriminator does in a GAN to prevent it from reaching a point where it's so good that the generator no longer has any chance of learning.

Comment: Just to be clear, this has nothing to do with convexity, at least as the authors have presented it. Also, we don't need to compute w.t() @ w or w @ w.t() explicitly to find the singular values (the power iteration algorithm used in the paper is an example of this, also `torch.svd` almost certainly doesn't explicitly represent the w.t() @ w matrix). Also, **every matrix, even non-square matrices have singular values, and they are always non-negative values.**